# Heroku failed to inject port number to process.env.PORT

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, graphql, express-graphql

I'm deploying my server to Heroku, but for some reason the network shows it keeps making request still to the localhost, instead of dynamically injecting a port number to process.env.PORT

[chrome console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Cs7.png)

This is the setup of my server.

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require('./schema/schema');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect(process.env.mongodburi, { useNewUrlParser: true })

mongoose.connection.once('open', ()=>{
  console.log('Connected to database');
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true
}));

app.withCredentials = true;

app.use('/', (req, res) => res.send("Welcome to read my profile"));

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log(`Now listening requests on port:${port}`);
})
```

Comment: You need to run `$ heroku config:set PORT=3333` before your server start

Comment: @ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ, that won't work. You can't pick your own port on Heroku. You _must_ use the port they give you.

Comment: The issue isn't the port the server is listening on. That appears to be correct. The issue is the address your _client is requesting_. Please edit your question and show some of the client code, e.g. a place where you request data from the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Or run `$ heroku config:set PORT=3333` as mentioned by ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ

Comment: The first option won't help. The issue isn't the address the _server_ is listening on, but rather the address the _client is requesting_. And the second option won't work. You can't pick your own port on Heroku. You _must_ use the port they give you.